# Query generated by Rails datamapper has "id" column name missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datamapper

So I have a class as shown below

```
class A
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  # other properties
```

When I run the following command

```
rake db:create db:migrate db:automigrate
```

I get the following error

```
rake aborted!
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "table_name" ( SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "on" INT...
```

I have noticed that the SQL should be

```
"id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

Can anyone help me as to why the "id" is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this by dropping the DB and running the automigrate before the migrate.